# Strange WMD bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

If you type the following characters into the WMD editor: `[some]` by themselves without wrapping them in backticks, firebug throws the following error:

```
K.replace is not a function
```

The odd thing is that I've only been able to reproduce this bug by typing those exact characters.  Any other combination of letters inside the brackets do not produce the error.

It looks like the return statement in `_DoAnchors()` does a regex replace using the method `writeAnchorTag`, which does this:

```
m4 = escapeCharacters(m4, '*_');
```

The error happens at `escapeCharacters` on this line:

```
return text.replace(regex, escapeCharacters_callback);
```

Comment: It seems to be if you type any member of the `Array` type, so `[concat]` and `[map]` mess up too. `some` just happens to [be one of them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem manifests itself in the `g_urls` cache array, which is used to lookup referenced URLs from elsewhere in the Markdown block when you use syntax like this:

```
[link text][id]

[id]: http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Markdown's syntax also lets you be lazy, which allowed you to more easily notice this bug. Consider the following, which also works:

```
[link text]

[link text]: http://stackoverflow.com/
```

You weren't trying to do that, but WMD can't read minds (...yet), so it went to look for the referenced URL anyway (since one wasn't specified yet), as part of `writeAnchorTag()`:

```
if (url == "") {
    if (link_id == "") {
        // lower-case and turn embedded newlines into spaces
        link_id = link_text.toLowerCase().replace(/ ?\n/g," ");
    }
    url = "#"+link_id;

    if (g_urls[link_id] != undefined) {
        url = g_urls[link_id];
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Based on the above, `[some]` results in a `link_id` of `some`, and `g_urls['some']` is defined, because `g_urls` is an array. This means that `url` becomes a reference to `g_urls`'s `some` function, which makes it a pretty poor candidate for performing a string replace on in `escapeCharacters()`.

A possible solution would either be to replace the array objects with plain ones, or use some sort of prefixing scheme on the keys.

Comment: Neat-o!  Good of you to look into it so thoroughly.  Worth coding in a conditional to catch these?  maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @Stephen: It does seem to break the preview box, so I think it would be nice to at least prevent the exception condition...but I'm just a curious investigator, so I guess we'll just have to wait and see if it's anything worth fixing. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build; thanks to [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64655/strange-wmd-bug/64676#64676) for debugging this. We now use a prefix on the keys; just going with `Object()` instead of `Array()` would still have left `__proto__` and `constructor` as a (albeit small) problem.